# git push heroku master: Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: django, heroku, github

I tried running:

```
$ git push heroku master    
-----

Total 7121 (delta 2300), reused 6879 (delta 2228)
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:fierce-atoll-4127.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:fierce-atoll-4127.git'
```

The only possible answers that I have found suggested that if you have an underscore in your app name, it might cause this problem. I had a "-" and I removed it, but I still can't get this work.

The following is in my requirements.txt, which sits under my src folder, alongside settings.py and manage.py.

```
Django==1.4.3
South==0.7.6
distribute==0.6.31
ipython==0.13.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
dj-database-url==0.2.0
```

Comment: Which platform web app are you pushing?  Rails or PHP or some other?

Comment: you need the requirements.txt file in the root of the project!

Answer (score 33):

Just had this problem too. I did the following to solve it: (assuming you're in project dir)

```
rm -rf .git
git init 
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```

A slightly involved solution to create a new application, but at least it works. Hope that helps!

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me after trying many of the other solutions.

Comment: This one worked for me. (I edited the answer to include the -m flag FYI)

Comment: Note: this solution will delete your git history. Only do this if you don't mind losing it.

Answer (score 13):

You probably need to add a `requirements.txt` file. check the python app docs

Comment: Hi, just curious. How yu saying it was Python app?

Comment: This ended up being my problem. Missspelled requirements.txt.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue and in my case was because my apps were outside of my project folder. Heroku expects to have this structure:

```
Procfile
requirements.txt
static/
myproject/
  manage.py
  app1/
  app2/
  ..
```

Comment: This doesn't look right; Django normally has the app folders (app1, app2 in your example) on the same level as manage.py.

Answer (score 3):

```
rm -rf .git
git init 
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```

This worked for me as well !

Comment: This worked for me with the additional step of running   `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`.

Answer (score 2):

Since Django is a python app, you'll need to have `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` sit in the root of your repo and not the src sub-directory. See https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect

Answer (score 2):

My stupid error was to mispell `requirements.txt` as the erroneous `requirments.txt`.  I didn't need `setup.py`.

Additionally I need to actually store the git repository in Github.  Just creating it locally wasn't enough.

Comment: +1 : I did exactly the same thing now, and this answer made me double check the file name. doh :-)

Comment: That's weird - you shouldn't need to push it to Github, from what I understand.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone deleting their Git history to make this work... the only reason that works is because the initial commit in the new repository contains the necessary files for Heroku to recognize your app.

I ran into this problem because I added the `Procfile` and `requirements.txt` for my app and tried to push to Heroku before actually committing them. So when I pushed to Heroku, I wasn't pushing those files!

Making a commit with all the necessary files and *then* pushing should solve this problem, and is vastly preferable to deleting your entire Git history.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, I was having this problem and I had pulled the repo from Heroku and then made a single character change somewhere and when pushing, the error comes. The creating a new Heroku app solution works though.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue for a long time and the only solution was [Vincent van Leeuwen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236643/5764461), but I didn't understand why. The problem turned out to be that I was working from a local branch other than master. So when I was running

```
git push heroku master
```

I was actually pushing

```
(local) master->(heroku) master
```

and not

```
(local) current_branch -> (heroku) master
```

as I intended. This failed because my local master branch didn't have requirements.txt, Procfile, etc.

The solution is:

```
git push heroku current_branch:master
```

See [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) for more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped and solved my issue. Thank you so much! Should be up above before people delete their entire Git Histories

Answer (score 1):

Heroku needs a requirements.txt file, which helps Heroku know what dependencies need to be installed for your Django project. You can use a tool generate your requirements.txt file.

Run in command line

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

which will create a requirements.txt file with all your installed packages, such as Django, django-registration, etc...

This link may be helpful: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/deploy/README.html

Answer (score 1):

My situation is that my codes are needed to save both on Github and Heroku, if I use the following solution, `rm -rf .git` will delete the connection to my Github, therefore I can't push my codes to Github.

```
rm -rf .git
git init 
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
heroku create --stack cedar-14
git push heroku master
```

Instead, my solution is as follows:

```
$ heroku create
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
$ git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above solutions dont mention that what matters is where is your .git initialised. Actually when you try push on heroku you should be doing it from the directory where you had initialsed the git itself.
Also the directory you are uploading should be the one where you have files like

- requirements.txt, Procfile, virtualenv, manage.py and .gitignore

  etc.
  In short Heroku needs all files to understand the type of project you want to upload so these files should be accessible on the root directory.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the requirement.txt file to git and then push it will work of sure.