# DJANGO "Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected" -- Git Issue

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, web-deployment

I'm following instructions, as per: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

I've ensured that all the necessary files are there, spelled correctly (Procfile, requirements.txt, etc.).

I'm getting this error:

```
$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 85, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (52/52), done.
Writing objects: 100% (85/85), 19.22 KiB, done.
Total 85 (delta 32), reused 78 (delta 29)


 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:gentle-forest-5173.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:gentle-forest-5173.git'
```

I believe I know the error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I skipped the step where I am to create a new git repo, because the directory I'm working is already tied to a git repo, I figured I didn't need to do this.

Thinking that this may be the issue, I followed the top answer here: [git push heroku master: Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939881/git-push-heroku-master-heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected)

which suggests to do this:

```
rm -rf .git
git init 
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```

This worked to get the app online, but then it lost ties to the github repo I was committing to, I believe because of the `rm -rf git`.

Is there a way to upload this so that, I can clone an existing project off github, follow the instructions on the Heroku Django deployment guide, but tailor it so its still tied to my online repo?

Comment: If you really have a file named "Procile", then you definitely haven't ensured that all the files are spelled correctly.

Comment: @DanielRoseman just a typo there, thanks though. as i said, i've got it to run when I followed that last block of commands, but then it removed my connection to the git repo that I originally cloned it from.