# Getting error while deploying Django app in the Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django project and I was trying for the first time to deploy in the 
Heroku cloud. The project structure is as following,

```
# Project structure:

.\Project folder\ -
                |
                |- .\env\ (Virtual enviroment )
                |
                |- .\src\ -
                |          |
                |          |- .\main\ -
                |          |           |
                |          |           |- admin.py  (Output tables data in to admin dashboard)
                |          |           |- models.py (Classes os DB tables)
                |          |           |- serializers.py (Serializing of data output in API)
                |          |           |- views.py (Custome API views)
                |          |           |- ...
                |          |
                |          |- .\users_groups\ -
                |          |                   |
                |          |                   |- settings.py (Project settings)
                |          |                   |- urls.py ( file with URL's reg. ex. patterns)
                |          |                   |- wsgi.py
                |          |
                |          |- .\templates\ 
                |          |
                |          |- manage.py
                |          |- db.sqlite3
                |
                |- .\app-messages
                |
                |- ReadMe.txt 
                |
                |- requirements.txt (file with list of all dependencies for app)
```

My [project](https://github.com/Chaklader/TeamManagementApp) is here and I followed [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html) tutorial. I was inside the `.\Project folder\` and at the time of `pushing` in the master, I get some error. I use the command to push,

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the error message,

```
To https://git.heroku.com/i2x-team-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/i2x-team-app.git'
```

What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: tru push to another branch

Comment: What do you mean? I know Git but this is the first time I use Heroku.

Comment: where is `Procfile` ?

Comment: I added the `Procfile` in the project after I pushed the repo in the Github. Is that matter ? BTW, I just pushed the updated version (incl. `Procfile` ) in the Github and you can see it.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939881/git-push-heroku-master-heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected

Comment: The issue is not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

Then push